# How to access the new innerHTML value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cookies, getelementbyid

I have this initial html before anything is ran:

```
<p id="displayUsers"> Hello </p>
```

I click a button and on screen that hello gets replaced by a cookie value e.g. `lGJMAfWVXSXCChEAAtXaQU1QHNU2` with the code below

```
function nextUser(users_array) {
  printUser.innerHTML = _USERS[myIndex++ % _USERS.length].useruid
}
```

I then have this variable set:

```
var userUidDisplayedValue = document.getElementById('displayUsers').innerHTML;
```

I click a button to run the `nextUser()` and it will iterate through the array of cookie values as above.

I then click another button that runs the `mapUidToUser()` as below

```
function mapUidToUser(){
  console.log(userUidDisplayedValue);
}
```

The log still displays **hello** instead of the value of a cookie as should now be in the `innerHTML`. 
for some reason the value is not updating. any ideas why?

Comment: If your variable is set outside of any function that you use for interaction, it's value won't change. If you'd put `userUidDisplayedValue = document.getElementById('displayUsers').innerHTML;` inside the `nextUser()` function (or any function that you think it's feasible to update the value), then the variable would now hold the correct value

Comment: You might find this fiddle useful: https://jsfiddle.net/t4oyL319/1/

Comment: very helpful. cheers!